# Select record if a value exists else another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Really struggling with this and I don't know why.  My table looks like this:

```
FundID    BenchmarkID    BenchmarkType  StartDate    EndDate
A         1              Primary        2018-06-01   NULL
A         2              Reporting 1    2018-06-01   NULL
B         1              Primary        2018-07-01   NULL
C         2              Primary        2018-06-01   NULL
C         1              Reporting 1    2018-06-01   NULL
```

What I want to do is select only the records where there is a BenchmarkType of "Reporting 1", but if it doesn't have a Reporting 1 record then select the "Primary" BenchmarkType.  I will also need to use this as part of a join to other tables and it needs to be efficient.

So far my code is as follows and I've tried to be clever with a COALESCE but it is not working, as I said I need to be able to use this as part of a select and potentially in other queries as a join:

```
SELECT * FROM Benchmark
WHERE BenchmarkType = COALESCE(CASE WHEN BenchmarkType = 'Reporting 1' OR BenchmarkType = 'Primary' THEN 'Reporting 1' ELSE NULL END,'Primary')
AND EndDate IS NULL
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  If only these two types are available, then `union all` is simple enough:

```
select b.*
from Benchmark b
where BenchmarkType = 'Reporting 1'
union all
select b.*
from Benchmark b
where BenchmarkType = 'Primary' and
      not exists (select 1 from Benchmark b2 where b2.fundId = b.fundId and b2.BenchmarkType = 'Reporting 1');
```

Comment: I think `b.FundID = b2.FundID` will be needed in the `EXISTS` but it's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `row_number()` function with `top (1) with ties` ? :

```
select top (1) with ties b.*
from Benchmark b
order by row_number() over (partition by FundID 
                            order by (case when BenchmarkType = 'Reporting 1' 
                                           then 1 
                                           when BenchmarkType = 'Primary'
                                           then 2
                                      end)
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved in one select query:

```
select *
from Funds a
where BenchmarkType = 'Reporting 1' 
OR 
 ( benchmarktype = 'Primary' and fundid not in (select fundid from funds where benchmarktype = 'Reporting 1'))
```